# Presto: Last day of the month prior

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a list of dates.  I would like to return the last date of the month prior like the below example:

```
date            lastdayofmonthprior
'2018-04-03'    '2018-03-31'
```

I have tried `date_trunc('month', date('2018-04-03'))-1`, however, I get this error:

```
'-' cannot be applied to date, integer
```

I'm guessing I can't do arithmetic to a date in Presto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use DATE_ADD in Presto:

```
DATE_ADD('day', -1, date_trunc('month', date('2018-04-30')))
```

Comment: `date_trunc('month', date('2018-04-30')) - interval '1' day` as alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Since Presto [0.270](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.270.html?highlight=last_day_of_month) version [`last_day_of_month`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#last_day_of_month) function is available (At the moment of writing is not available in Amazon Athena):

```sql
select last_day_of_month(now() - interval '1' month);
```

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-06-30 |

**UPD**

Since [Athena engine version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference-0003.html) [functions are based on Trino](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html#functions-env3) so `last_day_of_month` should be supported in it.